# jQuery string + variable in var

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a very simple piece of code:

```
var psImg_path;
psImBG_path = psImgBG_split[0] + "overlayimages";

alert(psImgBG_path);
```

But it returns 'undefined'.
The weird thing is, is that if I alert psImgBG_split[0], it returns 'images'.

Comment: `psImBG_path != psImgBG_path` - `g` is missed in (`Img`)the variable name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Arun P Johny said

> psImBG_path != psImgBG_path - g is missed in (Img)the variable name

Answer (score 0):

```
var psImg_path;
psImg_path = psImgBG_split[0] + "overlayimages";

alert(psImg_path);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.